Symfony : Connect to an external database without creating Entities
I already set up connexions to two database which are on the same server. Both have entities related because I need to insert datas and retrieve datas from the tables.
But I'm wondering if I can connect to a database on another server without creating entities, just to select data from the tables ? Do I have to set up the connection in the doctrine.yml too ?
The fact is that I can connect to this database only under a VPN
If anyone have already encounter this case,
Thank you in advance !

Just open a new conection to the database with either PDO or MySQLi? No point in defining this connection in Doctrine because you don't want entities either way

You can use connect engine or spider to make one remote database table appear as local table with near identical functionality.

I hope this will help you.
In doctrine.yaml:
doctrine:
  dbal:
    default_connection: your_database
    connections:
      your_database:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        url: '%env(resolve:YOUR_DATABASE_URL)%'
        server_version: 8.0.38
        charset: utf8mb4

In YourRepository.php
namespace App\Repository;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Query\QueryBuilder;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;


class FooRepository
{
    public function __construct(
        private readonly ManagerRegistry $registry
    ) {}

    public function getFoo(): array
    {
        /** @var QueryBuilder $qb */
        $qb = $this->registry->getConnection('your_database')->createQueryBuilder();

        return $qb->select('id')
            ->addSelect('code')
            ->addSelect('is_active')
            ->from('foo')
            ->fetchAllAssociative();
    }

}

